# Azure deployment .NET app deployment scripts

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, webpack

My .NET Core 2 app uses build scripts (webpack), defined in .csproj file like so :

```
<Target Name="BuildScript" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="webpack" />
</Target>
```

This app is deployed to an Azure App Service through continuous deployment (Bitbucket). Deployment fails in "Running deployment command" obviously, because it tries to execute command "webpack".

I need my project to run webpack automatically during dev to bundle my js files ; but I don't want azure deployment to run webpack.

So what should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would using Target Condition help? Something like -

```
Condition="'$(CONFIG)'=='DEBUG'"
```

Reference: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx

Comment: Yes, my research led me to this possibility. Tried it out, and it works for me.
Precisely, I added a custom environment variable, that I can call in that "Condition" property.
It works, but I'm still open to remarks about the best way to manage this build stuff !